# Using the mongo C# driver, how to serialize an array of custom object in order to store it?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a product document that contains an array of documents. For example

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: "J-E-L-L-O",
 store:[{id: 1,
    name: "Store X"},
    {id: 2,
    name: "Store Y"}]
}
```

I would like to change the name of "Store Y" to Store Z", for instance. At the time, I don't know the index of the object. So, I pull the entire array, find the object to update, change the name, and then attempt to set the value of "store" with the updated array.

```
productCollection.Update(query, Update.Set("store", storeList.ToBsonDocument()));
```

However, I am getting an error: `"An Array value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document."`

I think I just need to know how to serialize the array of custom objects to an array of BsonDocuments.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately I had the same problem and ended up making an extension method to help me get around it.

```
    public static BsonArray ToBsonDocumentArray(this IEnumerable list)
    {
        var array = new BsonArray();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            array.Add(item.ToBson());
        }
        return array;
    }
```

so you should be able to do:

```
productCollection.Update(query, Update.Set("store", storeList.ToBsonDocumentArray()));
```

Comment: When I use the extension method that u mentioned i get the below error like: A String value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document. Any Ideas?

Comment: I guess this strictly applies to BsonArray type

Comment: @SunnySharma 6 years ago when I wrote that reply, it was quite specifically to the BsonArray type, yes. However I cannot answer for what the state of affairs with MongoDb may be today.

Answer (score 2):

The exception says that you cannot convert an array/list into a BsonDocument. I think that you are looking to convert `storeList` to a `[BsonArray][1]`.

If `storeList` is already an array of `BsonDocument` or some `IEnumerable<T>` where to can be converted to a `BsonDocument`, the you should not need to cast the `storeList` variable at all.

Comment: It's a Generic List of custom objects, so List<T>. Do I have to convert each element to a BsonDocument then put it in an array?

Answer (score 1):

Little edit for the accepted answer function:

```
public static BsonArray ToBsonDocumentArray(this IEnumerable list)
    {
        var array = new BsonArray();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            array.Add(item);
        }
        return array;
    }
```

we don't need to convert item.ToBson(). There is already an implicit conversion from string to bson.Thats the reason i was getting an error message "**A String value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document.**"

Comment: for me it says - "cannot convert from "object" to "MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue" at line #6 (array.Add(item))!

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
BsonDocument.Parse(storeList);
```

instead of

```
storeList.ToBsonDocument()
```

Comment: No, you cant use Parse since it is used on strings, not lists or other objects.