# C# MongoDB driver, filter doesn't work if I filter by array value

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq, request

I need to request some data from a database using C# mongodb driver and filter it. I create a filter and do request like so

```
public async Task GetForexFeedForTimeSpan(long fromUTCUnixtime, long toUTCUnixtime, Action<List<SymbolData>> onComplete, string[] forSymbols, int limit = 0) {

    List<SymbolData> list = new List<SymbolData>();
    FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter
        = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Where(bson =>
            forSymbols.Any(symbolName => bson["symbol"].AsString == symbolName) &&
            bson["timestamp"] >= fromUTCUnixtime &&
            bson["timestamp"] <= toUTCUnixtime

    );
    await GetCustomForexData(onComplete, filter, limit);


}



private async Task GetCustomForexData(Action<List<SymbolData>> onComplete, FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter, int limit = 0) {
    List<SymbolData> list = new List<SymbolData>();
    await m_SymbolsCollection 
        .Find(filter)
        .Limit(limit)
        .SortBy(bson => bson["timestamp"]).ForEachAsync(
        bson => {
            list.Add(SymbolData.FromBSON(bson));
        });
    onComplete?.Invoke(list);

}
```

Then I call it somewhere like this:

```
GetForexFeedForTimeSpan(fromUnixtime, toUnixtime, OnCompleteDelegate, new[]{ "EURUSD" });
```

The database itself really contains "symbol" keys. And if I change the filter to this

```
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter
            = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Where(bson =>
                (string)bson["symbol"]== "EURUSD" &&
                bson["timestamp"] >= fromUTCUnixtime &&
                bson["timestamp"] <= toUTCUnixtime

        );
```

It will work and find all documents with a symbol equal to "EURUSD". But I need to pass a bunch of symbol names and select any coincidences

Why doesn't it work with an array? Or maybe somebody can advise a better solution?

Comment: I think in Linq expression you can use ArrayList.Contains((string)bson[“symbol”]) function inside .Where or .Select..

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I even used custom function with simple FOR loop inside.

Comment: Can you please try using db profiler to see the query, not everything in Linq can be translated especially to nosql language.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707634/3254405

Comment: Although it would be better to serialize the query into a list and then use Linq https://stackoverflow.com/a/12076431/3254405

Comment: It throws an exception in background, saying that it cannot parse lambda expression. What do you mean by "serialize the query into a list and then use Linq"? Could you clarify this, please?

Comment: I misspoke about serializing, may be it’s called desirializing.. Basically try doing what this guy is saying but in a nosql way.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533408/3254405

Comment: Well, that seems like a good idea for now :) Thanks! I found another solution with joining filters, but I think I'll make use of it later